# Custom error page for TokenMismatchException laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I need a way to redirect and clear a specific cookie if this error occurs but as it doesn't have an actual URL i'm finding it difficult.

Answer (score 1):

In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file, in `report` method you can compare the instance of error with your required error type and return a view accordingly.

```
if($e instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException){
    return view('errors.404');
}
```